# Magento 2 Auto Language Redirect For Country

Tags: magento

I want to make automatic routing for my web site using Magento 2 according to the country. How can I do it?

Comment: Please add the code or process what you have done so far so someone can help you don't direcly ask questions in this way.

Comment: Please do some own research before asking on stackoverflow.

Comment: @digijay I did my research but couldn't find any source. I wonder if there's a way to do it for free.

Comment: @raju_eww Thanks for your comment. I'm using Stack Overflow for the first time. I didn't know the system was running like this, I'm sorry. I'm using Magento and I don't have any progress yet

Comment: @Secrax and did you for example have a [look at this?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/127081)

Comment: Thank you for help @digijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Auto Switch Language and Currency - Magento 2 ® Extensions](https://www.knowband.com/magento-2-auto-switch-language-currency) for this.  With the help of this Magento 2 auto switch language and currency extension, the eCommerce store owner can run the online store business all over the world.
This auto switch language plugin automatically sets the language and currency according to the customer’s geographical location. It switches the language on the basis of the customer’s IP address. The e-merchant can also select a default language for every country. The Magento 2 auto switch language plugin offers a user-friendly interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. looks fine. Thank you so much.